# Cashier 6.0 compatibility with Stripe API 15/08/2017

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-cashier

I'm running Laravel 5.2 and want to implement Cashier package (6.0, as 7.0 need L5.3) and Stripe. 
But I cannot find any compatibility table between Cashier and Stripe API versions.

- Do someone knows where to find a compatibility sheet?
- Is there any other way to see what's cashier 6.0 is compatible with?
- I can upgrade my Stripe API version, but I only have a 72h rollback possibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the Cashier repository it doesn't seem to specify which version of the Stripe API version it works with. However, it does look like it's a minimal wrapper around `stripe-php`, the Stripe PHP library. It may work fine, but with any API upgrade it's important to test your site thoroughly, run your tests, etc against the new API version. You can see a detailed explanation of what will change when you upgrade your API by reading through this page:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations

Beyond that I'd ask the maintainer of Cashier for their thoughts on compatibility across Stripe API versions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll contact the maintainer. If I'm able to get a compatibility sheet or close, I'll post it here.